# How do I delete files from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm brand new to Ubuntu One and cloud storage. On my Ubuntu 11.04 machine I created an account and uploaded the file with all of my projects to the Ubuntu One folder (not the Shared with Me folder). Then deleted it with a right-click "move to trash". Later I downloaded the Ubuntu One app to my Windows 7 machine and was surprised to see the folder show up there. So now its gone from 11.04 but shows on Windows 7. How do I remove it completely from the cloud forever so that nobody anywhere can access it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Sign in here: https://login.ubuntu.com/
2. Go to *Files*.
3. Click on *More* on the right side of the folder you want to remove.
4. Choose *'Delete folder' (or 'Delete file')*.

[image: Ubuntu One delete files screenshot]

Comment: Isn't that a rather user/session specific url?

Comment: @andol Indeed, thanks for telling me. Replaced it.

Comment: The link gives me "Invalid OpenID transaction". Can you tell me a little more about the link? Where is it supposed to take me?

Comment: Eh... To the login page of the Ubuntu One dashboard. It allows you to manage your files stored on your account using their website. You should use the same login you used for the Ubuntu One desktop application.

Comment: "Delete Folder" will appear for sub-folders as of 20140429.  It does not appear for the root shared folder.