# How can I delete files in Ubuntu One?

Tags: files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete files from Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66763/how-do-i-delete-files-from-ubuntu-one)

I am having difficulty deleting files in Ubuntu One. It does not delete, but it downloads. There needs to be more space on the site for the delete "button".

Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the Ubuntu One [web interface](https://one.ubuntu.com) and click on **Login**. Login with your email and password. Then, click con **Files** and navigate to the file you want to delete.

When you see the file, just click on *More* and then **Delete File**.

I hope it works to you!

Answer (score 1):

You can even delete file from folder "Ubuntu One", Which is located at your home folder. This will delete the file from server also.