# How do I delete files/folders from Ubuntu One web interface?

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete

I see this questions has been asked twice already;

[How do I delete files from Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66763/how-do-i-delete-files-from-ubuntu-one)
[How can I delete files in Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208131/how-can-i-delete-files-in-ubuntu-one)

but the answers do not work for me. I do not see a delete option when I click the more link. I only see "share folder" and "Stop syncing". I clicked stop syncing and nothing happens. I would like to delete an entire folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it is obscured by another inscription/link?

See that image:

[image]

Comment: Your deleting a file in that pic. I can't even get to the files. Im using google chrome. I want to delete an entire folder. Even if I click on a folder to view its contents, it just hangs, saying loading. I will try a different browser and see what happens.

Comment: Does the same thing in IE. There's not delete link. And when I try to open the folder the browser just hangs on 'Loading'